# Convert time object to datetime format in python pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a dataset of column name *DateTime* having dtype **object**.

```
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])
```

I have used the above code to convert to **datetime** format then did a split in the column to have **Date** and **Time** separately

```
df['date'] = df['DateTime'].dt.date
df['time'] = df['DateTime'].dt.time
```

but after the split the format changes to object type and while converting it to datetime it showing error for the *time* column name as: *TypeError:  is not convertible to datetime*

How to convert it to datetime format the **time** column

Comment: What do you mean "proper time format"...? Please show the code you're using that produces *TypeError: is not convertible to datetime*

Comment: The same code that I have showed to convert the DateTime i.e `df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.['time'])`

Comment: @NadeemHaque - converting to string is necessary like `df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.['time'].astype(str))` but then is added some dates, because datetimes with no dates not exist.

Comment: @jezrael I'm new to python so got confused.. thank you for the help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`combine`](https://docs.python.org/release/2.6/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.combine) in list comprehension with `zip`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'DateTime': ['2011-01-01 12:48:20', '2014-01-01 12:30:45']})
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])

df['date'] = df['DateTime'].dt.date
df['time'] = df['DateTime'].dt.time

import datetime
df['new'] = [datetime.datetime.combine(a, b) for a, b in zip(df['date'], df['time'])]
print (df)

             DateTime        date      time                 new
0 2011-01-01 12:48:20  2011-01-01  12:48:20 2011-01-01 12:48:20
1 2014-01-01 12:30:45  2014-01-01  12:30:45 2014-01-01 12:30:45
```

Or convert to strings, join together and convert again:

```
df['new'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].astype(str) + ' ' +df['time'].astype(str))
print (df)
             DateTime        date      time                 new
0 2011-01-01 12:48:20  2011-01-01  12:48:20 2011-01-01 12:48:20
1 2014-01-01 12:30:45  2014-01-01  12:30:45 2014-01-01 12:30:45
```

But if use `floor` for remove times with converting times to timedeltas then use `+` only:

```
df['date'] = df['DateTime'].dt.floor('d')
df['time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['DateTime'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S'))

df['new'] = df['date'] + df['time']
print (df)

             DateTime       date     time                 new
0 2011-01-01 12:48:20 2011-01-01 12:48:20 2011-01-01 12:48:20
1 2014-01-01 12:30:45 2014-01-01 12:30:45 2014-01-01 12:30:45
```

Answer (score 1):

> How to convert it back to datetime format the time column

There appears to be a misunderstanding. Pandas `datetime` series **must** include date and time components. This is non-negotiable. You can simply use `pd.to_datetime` without specifying a date and use the default `1900-01-01` date:

```
# date from jezrael

print(pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%H:%M:%S'))

0   1900-01-01 12:48:20
1   1900-01-01 12:30:45
Name: time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Or use another date component, for example today's date:

```
today = pd.Timestamp('today').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print(pd.to_datetime(today + ' '  + df['time'].astype(str)))

0   2018-11-25 12:48:20
1   2018-11-25 12:30:45
Name: time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Or recombine from your `date` and `time` series:

```
print(pd.to_datetime(df['date'].astype(str) + ' ' + df['time'].astype(str)))

0   2011-01-01 12:48:20
1   2014-01-01 12:30:45
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```